# Markdown selection issue. Button inserts content but I want part of it to be selected

Tags: jquery

So I created a button. When you click this button it inserts some markdown code.
Here is my MarkDown code:

```
   $('button.bold').click(function(){ 
   $('#body').val($('#body').val()+'**Bold text here**'); 
   })
```

When I click this button it see this in the text field:

```
**Bold text here**
```

What I want to do is select Bold text here. So when a user wants to make a bold text the Bold text here goes away.

It is currently like this when I push the button:[image: Current]
But I would like mine to be:
[image: Would like]

Thanks for the help. I hope I was clear about what I wanted.

Comment: I tried to add .select() at the end but that did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following function to your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.fn.extend({
    setSelection: function(selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
        if(this.length == 0) return this;
        input = this[0];

        if (input.createTextRange) {
            var range = input.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
            range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
            range.select();
        } else if (input.setSelectionRange) {
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }

        return this;
    }
});
});
```

And modify your jQuery code as follows

```
$('button.bold').click(function(){ 
   $('#body').val($('#body').val()+'**Bold text here**');
   var start = $('#body').val().indexOf('**Bold text here** ')+2;
   var end = $('#body').val().indexOf('**Bold text here** ')+16;
   $('#body').setSelection(start, end);
})
```

**Check the updated fiddle at:** http://jsfiddle.net/26z7b110/1/

**Reference**: http://richonrails.com/articles/text-area-manipulation-with-jquery

Have used the site's brilliant jQuery extending function. Consider adding any more (of the other 4) functions you feel helpful

Comment: Check out the new approach. Much neater and the reference would help you with further functions as well.